# how can I send token in header authentication Bearer to Browser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, restful-authentication

that is my code in helper signin router 
so I'm trying to set cookie to browser after confirm sign in

```
exports.signin = (req,res) => {
        db.User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).then(user => {
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password,function(err,isMatch){
                if(isMatch){
                    let token = jwt.sign({userId: user.id},process.env.SECRET_KEY,{ expiresIn: 60*5 });
                    res.setHeader() //here I wanna send header Bearer to the browser 
                } else {
                    res.status(400).json({message:"Incorrect Password!"});
                }
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(404).send('No user found.');  
        })**strong text**
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Authorization header is a client header, you cannot set it on the server(Server does not need authorization). You need to send it in a JSON response and then handle it in the client side.

Your server sends a JSON response with the token.
Your client sets the Authorization header and send it to any route that reaquires authorization

javascript client example:

```
var myHeaders =  new Headers()

/**you need to get the token and put it in myToken var.
   Where to store the token is the real question, you need
   to take care about the storage you choose beacause of
   the security risks*/

myHeaders.append('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myToken);

fetch( '/myurl', {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: myHeaders,
    method: 'GET'
}).then( res => {

    return res.json();

}).then( res => {

    /**your stuff*/
    
});
```

Then in your server check for the headers and you will see the Bearer

Comment: i think this answer is elegible to be valid, but it is missing the "how". over inside of expressjs you can res.send("your token here") alright, but once it is sent, the client will receive it as a json file (especially if you want to send other user info like name or email). Alright, now, on the client side, how exactly the client will set the token as a header? cuz for example, to access the dashboard, the user will need the auth, the token must be there in the header. how?

Answer (score 2):

In Node.js res.setHeader() and Express js res.header() is an alias of res.set() method.

you can use in following ways :

```
res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token); 
res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token);
```

But I recommend you to read jwt example (angularjs & node) : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543